# How to map array of filtered results to original array (with value semantics)?

Tags: ios, swift

I implemented typical text filtering functionality. My class has one array, where all the original values are stored, and another, where I store the filtered values, which are shown to the user.

Then the users can do things with the values (when they are filtered as well as when they are not filtered), e.g. set status as "selected". So the objects have to be updated.

Normally I would have solved this via references. So my 2 arrays reference the same objects, and when I change something in the currently shown (filtered) results, the object is also updated in the array with the original values. Quite simple...

But now it turns out that a recent version of Swift changed arrays to be partially "value-only", so my update via reference doesn't work. If I update object A in the filtered array, object A in the original array is not updated.

On the other side, it's possible to update via subscripting:

```
array[i] = updatedObj
```

But I still have to update the filtered and the original array separately... I could represent the filtered array with a list of only indices instead of model objects but I don't want to do this, because who knows, maybe I want to support resorting of results at some point and then everything is broken. I know I can find solutions for this but I suspect there is a different, better solution.

The most straight forward approach is to iterate through the filtered array, using indices, then iterate through the original-objects array to find the matching object (using == and/or some id), and then, set updated object via subscripting in the original array.

This is safe but on the other side I'm developing a mobile application and this is not very performance friendly.

A filtered list is some of those use cases where an update via reference is justified imo, since the filtered array is really just a "view" on top of the original array. Is there an elegant/performant solution for this in Swift?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to do this by making your base array and filtered array NSArray types rather than Swift Array types.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your problem. But Swift `Array` still can hold reference type objects. And your update on the filtered array elements affects original array elements.

with Swift 1.2 / Xcode Version 6.3 Beta2 (6D532l)

```
class Foo {
    var val = 0
}

let originalArray:[Foo] = [Foo(),Foo(), Foo(), Foo()]
let filteredArray:[Foo] = Array(originalArray[1...2])

filteredArray[0].val = 12
let obj = filteredArray[1]
obj.val = 42

originalArray[0].val // -> 0
originalArray[1].val // -> 12
originalArray[2].val // -> 42
originalArray[3].val // -> 0
```

Comment: I just tested, the difference is that I was using a struct instead of a class. It's weird since nevertheless my struct has vars so it's mutable, but this doesn't seem to apply when used in arrays....... unless accessed via subscripting. Also interesting, when using struct filteredArray has to be declared as var in order for assignment to work.